# Etsy links in embedly

Tags: etsy, embedly

Good afternoon:

I am an ETSY affiliate through the AWIN platform. I am having problems when generating affiliate links. The message that I get is this

Unable to embed this url
Embedly is unable to generate an embed for this URL. Please check that the URL is valid (has an http prefix: ex. http://embed.ly) and that the content is publically accessable.

The point is that although I put the direct link of etsy (without affiliate) I still get the same error

https://www.etsy.com/es/listing/520698100/amigurumi-del-sombrerero-loco-de-alicia?ref=shop_home_active_1

Regards, Marina

Answer (score -1):

Probably because embedly doesn't have a free plan.

However, You can use https://microlink.io:

https://api.microlink.io/?url=https://www.etsy.com/es/listing/520698100/amigurumi-del-sombrerero-loco-de-alicia?ref=shop_home_active_1